# How to reduce top and bottom padding of Material3 NavigationBar

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, navigationbar, android-navigation-bar

I am using material3 NavigationBar for the bottom navigation, inside the `bottomBar` slot of a Scaffold.
Even in the specs, it look very thick - https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/specs

How do I remove some padding from the top and bottom of the icon/text to make it more slender?

[image]

When I play with the height, it makes the text and icon overlap, but keeps the big padding intact.

[image: navigationBar with lower height]

Trying to play with the windows insets, like other answers here suggested did not yield what I am looking for. Then again, the explanation to use them was not very clear.

Looking at the top and bottom padding of the NavigationBarDefaults.windowsInsets.getTop/Bottom yields zeros.

Not using modifiers, this is out of the box components. Only added modifiers to color the background and change height for testing only ,to produce the screenshots.

```
NavigationBar {
    tabs.forEach { tab ->
        NavigationBarItem(label=..., icon=..., onClick=..., selected=...)
   }
}
```

Here's the code that produced the green squashed bar

```
NavigationBar(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp)) {
    tabs.forEach { tab ->
        NavigationBarItem(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.green), label=..., icon=..., onClick=..., selected=...)
   }
}
```

Comment: Drop your Modifiers or Code snippet please.

Comment: I added, but I did not use modifiers for this. It's out of the box the way it looks. I'm looking for the right modifier or property to change to reduce it's thickness

Comment: How yours label is overlapping on the icon because when I apply modifier with height on NavigationBar{}, it cuts down label if there is a lesser height.

Comment: It's in a Scaffold... Do you think that's the issue?

Comment: Not really.... I added for both `bottomBar{}` and `content{ column{...} }`. It cuts down the Text(). Even if not wrapped with `Scaffold()` (just `Surface{ column{} }`.